# Use window.print() to generate report

Tags: javascript, printing

I have a print button on my page that will run window.print(), it just prints the page exactly. Is there a way to modify the output when window.print() has been clicked?

Comment: Your research keyword is _print stylesheet_.

Comment: But can I change the output? Or should I say the content?

Comment: @JaeEun: Use CSS to hide and show elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting

```
@media print {
  // print only styles...
}
```

in your css will allow to specify your print only output.  This is where you would override/add any screen styling.

Update:

Example to hide a button from print:

```
@media print {
  /* button selectors */
  .btn, button, submit { 
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Comment: If you want to add content to print only, you would assign display: none outside of the @media print block and override it inside of the print block... or vise versa.

Comment: Is it also the same way of hiding the button when you print the page? Thanks a lot

Comment: Yes, example:

@media print {
  .btn { /* button selector */
    display: none;
  }
}